# Problems installing pear package (Failed loading /usr/lib64/php4/php_ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_x86_64.so)

Tags: php, pear

Trying to install pear package and keep getting this strange error. Can you shed any light on it?

```
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php4/php_ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_x86_64.so:  /usr/lib64/php4/php_ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_x86_64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Full message:

```
root@www webapps]# pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/soap-0.12.0
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php4/php_ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_x86_64.so:  /usr/lib64/php4/php_ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_x86_64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update pear.php.net" to update
pear/SOAP requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.4), installed version is 1.4.9
pear/Mail_Mime requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.6.0), installed version is 1.4.9
pear/Mail_mimeDecode requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.6.0), installed version is 1.4.9
pear/Mail_mimeDecode requires package "pear/Mail_Mime" (version >= 1.4.0, excluded versions: 1.4.0)
No valid packages found
install failed
[root@www webapps]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolve your problem: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=8051

Comment: Didn't directly fix it but giving me a good place to start research.

Comment: Sorry, try this http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2008/10/zendoptimizer-installation-on-linux-server-with-ioncube/, if this can not solve your problem, sorry.